# Newb question - Mageplaza SMTP installed but still regular php mail being used. Where to change default? - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hi all I installed the MagePlaza SMTP plugin, but the emails are still going through php mail and NOT my new SMTP settings through the plugin? Where do I change those settings? Is there a php file I need to update?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing configuration in the admin panel. Here are the [docs](https://docs.mageplaza.com/smtp-m2/).

What I most commonly use when setting up SMTP, is my gmail account. It's important to note, though, that the password referenced in the config for the email provider is **not** your email password. Using gmail as an example, you would need to go to "Manage Your Account" -> Security -> Signing into Google -> App Passwords. Then, for the app you would select "Other" and create it. That will give you the key that you would then use for the service provider field...